# Vectorizing S4 Class in R

Tags: r, performance, vectorization, convolution, log-likelihood

I am trying to compute a log-likelihood, where the likelihood is a convolution of two distributions, and the distribution parameters depend on the value of that data point.  More formally, I believe my data follows a likelihood which is the sum of two gamma distributions, which have separate shape and scale parameters and the shape parameter is a function of data.  Written mathematically, y<sub>i</sub>=pGamma(k<sub>1</sub>+b<sub>1</sub> x<sub>i</sub>, t<sub>1</sub>)+(1-p)Gamma(k<sub>2</sub>+b<sub>2</sub> x<sub>i</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>).  Note the plus sign is an arithmetic operation on the random variables, not between the CDFs.  This is not a mixture model.
The likelihood is a convolution between weighted random variables that have to be done per observation, which is very slow.

I currently am using the distr package, and this is what I have to compute the likelihood.

```
  sapply(1:10000, function(i){distr::d(p*Gammad(shape = k1+b1*x[i], scale = t1)+(1-p)*Gammad(shape = k2+b2*x[i], scale = t2))(y[i])})
```

Is there a way to vectorize this? Is there any other way to speed up the code?

When I try

```
distr::d(Vectorize(p*Gammad(shape = k1+b1*x, scale = t1)+(1-p)*Gammad(shape = k2+b2*x, scale = t2)))(y)
```

I get the error "Error in .multm(e1, e2, "AbscontDistribution") :
length of operator must be 1"

Comment: *"When I try to, I get an error."* How do you try? What is your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if

```
A ~ Gamma(k1 + b1*xi, t1)
B ~ Gamma(k2 + b2*xi, t2)
```

then

```
p*A ~ Gamma(k1 + b1*xi, p*t1)
(1 - p)*B ~ Gamma(k2 + b2*xi, (1 - p)*t2)
```

The closed-form PDF of the sum of two gamma random variates is [known](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/252192/214015) and involves Kummer's (confluent hypergeometric) function.

Using `chf_1F1` from the `scModels` package, I believe the following function would return the log-likelihoods.

```
library(scModels)

LL <- function(k1, b1, t1, k2, b2, t2, x, p, y) {
  a1 <- k1 + b1*x
  a2 <- k2 + b2*x
  a <- a1 + a2
  b1 <- 1/(p*t1)
  b2 <- 1/((1 - p)*t2)
  a1*log(b1) + a2*log(b2) - lgamma(a) - b1*y + (a - 1)*log(y) + chf_1F1((b1 - b2)*y, a2, a)
}
```